# Rails query to find record between two dates takes longer time when range is large

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord, psql

in my model, i have

```
joins(:address).where("addresses.zipcode IN(?) AND accounts.created_at >= ? AND accounts.created_at <= ?", zipcodes, from_date, to_date)
```

this works fine. but i have used this method in my controller, and on exiting that function in controller, if date range is higher (around 50-60 years). it takes 7-8 seconds to render result, duration increases with increase in date range. 
And in the terminal, i see query keeps on loading, checking for each and every single date. How do i reduce this time?

Comment: I am not sure about how much time it should take but you mentioned it **check for each and every single date** so if you can post logs from the server console of what SQL it fires each time, it might help to optimize.

Comment: `.where(addresses: { created_at:  from_date..to_date, zipcode: zipcodes } )` This will create a `WHERE addresses.created_at BETWEEN`.

Comment: If that does not help we need additional info about your schema and a logs and reproducible example to be able to help you further. You may want to use [EXPLAIN](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-explain.html) to figure out why the query is so slow.

Answer (score 2):

Add indexes on `accounts.create_at` and `addresses.zipcode`